# How to get AndroidManifest property with gradle

Tags: android, gradle, xml-parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.nd.component"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="0.1.0-SNAPSHOT">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>


<application>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainContainerActivity"
        android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        />


    <activity
        android:name="com.nd.component.update.DownloadActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"/>

    <permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER"/>
</application>
```

How can I  get the First activity's "windowSoftInputMode" value by using gradle.

In fact , i get some trouble when trying to get the "android:versoinCode" value.

Here's my gradle code.

```
task parsexx() {
def parseXmlFile = (new XmlParser()).parse('AndroidManifest.xml');
println parseXmlFile.@package
def android_versionCode = 'android:versionCode'
println "${android_versionCode}"
println parseXmlFile.@"${android_versionCode}"
println parseXmlFile.@${android_versionCode}
}
```

It's OK to get package's name by using this code, but return null when I try to get "android:versionCode".

Sorry for my poor English...

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by myself.

```
task parsexxx() {
  def manifest = new XmlSlurper().parse('AndroidManifest.xml').declareNamespace(android:'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android');
  println manifest.@package
  manifest.application.activity.each { 
  def m = it.attributes()['android:name'] =~ /MainContainerActivity/
    if (m.find()) {
        println "FOUND!"
        if (it.attributes()['android:windowSoftInputMode'] == "adjustPan") {
        println "Attribute Found!"
        it.@'android:windowSoftInputMode' = "adjustResize" 
        println it.@'android:windowSoftInputMode'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `adjustResize` is not applied. And the manifest in your APK will contain `adjustPan`